# Appropriate probability threshold for Jarque-Bera test

Tags: distributions, normality-assumption, quantiles

If a probability distribution has, say, 112 bins with around 29000 samples, with the maximum probability of a bin being less than 0.05, is the Jarque-Bera test an effective measure of conformance to a Normal distribution?

I'm working with univariate data, whose probability distribution 'looks' normal, with some deviation. However, the Jarque-Bera test for normality indicates that it is *not* normal.

Also, since n ~ 29000, the JB statistic is inflated to a ridiculous value like 1474523. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be most welcome.

The Jarque Bera statistics and a histogram for these data are:

```
n = 28535.0
Skewness = -4.24685767755943
Kurtosis = 37.1765663807246
JB statistic = 1474523.40413686
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: You can look at the probability distribution here:
http://d2o7bfz2il9cb7.cloudfront.net/main-qimg-1e9b09e9dddbf6650ff1937f46ba9f57

Comment: That's not even remotely normal!  The enormous JB statistic is merely telling you what is plainly obvious in the histogram.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working with univariate data, whose probability distribution 'looks' normal, with some deviation. However, the Jarque-Bera test for normality indicates that it is not normal.

You have relied on a visual 'measure' for inferring normality. I think you should be equipped with other visualization tools that must be used when looking for normality.

a) [Q-Q plot](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/qqplot.htm)-
have a look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78504/visually-inspecting-normality-of-variables) on this site.

A quantile means the fraction of points below that value. Ex- 0.25 quantile means the value below which 25% of the data is present.

b) [Normal probability plot](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/normprpl.htm)

The data are plotted against a theoretical normal distribution in such a way that the points should form an approximate straight line. Departures from this straight line indicates departure from normality.

c) Histogram

The histogram graphically shows many things about a distribution that includes the center (i.e., the location) of the data, spread (i.e., the scale) of the data, skewness of the data, presence of outliers. But one needs to [be careful with this!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram/51753#51753)

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

**That's not even remotely normal**! The enormous JB statistic is merely telling you what is plainly obvious in the histogram. – whuber