# How to translate a histogram to natural language?

Tags: distributions, histogram, fuzzy

Assume we have a set of histograms, let's say they describe age distribution of some people.

We want to translate this:

```
  x
  x x
x x x x x x
```

to: *mostly young*; and this:

```
      x
    x x x
x x x x x x
```

to: *mostly middle-age*; and this:

```
  x
  x x   x
x x x x x x
```

to, probably: *mostly young with some old*. There could be more complicated cases.

Which fields can help with this?

Fuzzy logic sounds like to be helpful, but I cannot see how it can help with distributions.

Comment: I don't think proper fuzzy logic would apply here.  It would very much depend on how exactly your data is stored; if it can be transformed into a dictionary-like structure, a python script could pretty easily do this using percentages of the whole.

Comment: Do you mean treating each histogram bin as a dictionary item? If so, how can a pattern like _mostly young_ be extracted from a dictionary?

Comment: Say the structure was `age_toys = {1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 8, 4: 15, ..., 15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 1, 18: 1, ...}`, you would find the highest holders of toys and then compare them; if there is a large gap: *mostly* 4 year olds; a smaller gap: *some* 4 year olds and *some* 5 year olds; etc.

Comment: Here's something that might [suggest a problem with the notion](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51753/805) - such a system will characterize those 4 plots differently, just as a human might. At the least, it suggests a need for a large caveat with such an automatic system.

Comment: How is that answer linked to comparing a given histogram to a template?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you could define histograms for "young", "middle-aged", etc, then convolve them with your histogram and set a threshold for "mostly" and "some".

Comment: This is like template matching. One problem with this is that the input histogram bin size is dynamic, and the convolution will require creating a template histogram of a given size dynamically.