# Suitable graph to visualize the spread of data

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have some data like

```
A  2
A  4
A  76
B  8
B  13
.. ....
```

Basically, what is the spread of A, B, etc.
What would be a suitable graph to visualize such information in R?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your data. How many points might there be for "A", "B", etc? Are the values in the second column presumably continuous?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your response. The numeric values are age, so numeric data is not continuous but discrete. There can be any number of points for A, B, etc., ranging from, say, 1 to 150.

Comment: How many values in each group?

Comment: So, there can be varying number of values in each group. Say, 20 for A and then 100 for B and then maybe 67 for C, and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are numerous possible displays, depending on what more specifically you want.

One example would be a [boxplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) for each group (A, B, ...) (assuming there are enough values in each group to support one*):

```
boxplot(len~supp,data=ToothGrowth,horizontal=TRUE,boxwex=.7)
```

[image: boxp]

But you might want to look at histograms, ecdfs, or a number of other possibilities

* Edit: from your later comments, it looks like there's enough data for boxplots.

Comment: Excellent! Let me try this!

Comment: Some other possibilities that haven't been mentioned in the answers yet would include Q-Q plots, beeswarm/beehive plots, and violin plots

Answer (score 9):

You already got some excellent answers but let me suggest another plot that was not mentioned yet (this is an example that I created to answer another question):

[image: Dot plot]

In R, it is available e.g. through `stripchart()` or ggplot2's `geom_point()` or `geom_jitter()`. (Jitter adds a little bit of noise to avoid too much overlap.) This plot allows you to look at the data somewhat more directly than histograms (which can be badly misleading, see Glen_b's [great answer to another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-histogram/51753#51753)) or boxplots (which are great but a little more complicated to understand and explain).

In GGPlot, you can also combine boxplots and jittered dots, see [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_jitter.html).

Comment: +1. There are many, many names for this plot. Dot and strip plots or charts are two of the most common. As "dot" is widely used in other senses, the name element "strip" is perhaps preferable, at least in searching for implementations (there are several, not just in R but also in all leading packages or languages, e.g. Stata `stripplot`).

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: @NickCox +1 Thanks for the precisions, I was so confused by the names that I tried very hard not to choose one… Your comment reminded me of another R function to create a stripchart (now added to my answer).

Comment: But how do I make this if one of the axes doesn't have any numeric data?

Comment: No problem i did it - ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=mydata, mapping=aes(x=mydata[,3], y=mydata[,2])) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(5, 90)) + xlab("Age") +
    ylab("Something") +
    ggtitle("Demographic Analysis of Age and something")

Comment: As the number of points increases, I would also suggest adding transparency *as well as* jitter. Or, you can use hollow circles.... These are created somewhat, by default, when using the `densityplot()` function from "lattice".

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by Glen_b, there are a number of possibilities.

Here is an example of a histogram and density plot using the "lattice" package. I've also provided some sample data.

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(V1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 500, replace = TRUE),
                   V2 = sample(0:50, 500, replace = TRUE))
head(mydf)
tail(mydf)
library(lattice)
histogram(~V2 | V1, data = mydf)
```

[image]

```
densityplot(~V2 | V1, data = mydf)
```

[image]

Both are with default settings applied.