# R - glm() - what is the family of glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, standard-error

When I'm fitting a generalized linear model, I use the [glm()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html) function like this:

```
fit <- glm(formula=y ~ x, 
           data=someFrame, 
           family=gaussian(link="log"))
```

But I don't know, what does the name of the family mean. It's described like this in the [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html):

*Family objects provide a convenient way to specify the details of the models used by functions such as glm. See the documentation for glm for the details on how such model fitting takes place.*

But still, I don't know, what is it exactly. Is it an estimated distribution of observed data?

Comment: Have you looked at any information about GLMs? For example [Wikipedia's page on GLMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model), in particular the section on [model components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Model_components)? There's also a table of the most commonly used distributions lower down on that page. Introductory documents on GLMs may be even more useful. Note that the distribution is a model for the conditional distribution of the response.

Answer (score -3):

GLMs are generalized Linear models with three components -  probability distribution, a linear predictor, and a link function that relates the linear predictor to the expected value of the probability distribution for the response which I will denote as Y.

The family argument here helps define the link function.

This link function provides a transformation of the response variable(Y) which is now linearly related to the predictors.

Comment: I know, what the link function is. But, for example `gaussian(link="log")` differs from `poisson(link="log")`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes they are different , while one being discrete distribution and  the other being continous distribution , and depending on the problem problem statement for example if you have event time based modelling , you may use poisson. refer to this, may help [link] http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94852/glm-gaussian-vs-glm-binomial-vs-log-link-glm-gaussian

Comment: The Family by itself do not define the link function, for instance, binomial Family can have logir, probit, complementary loglog, or other link functions.

Comment: Incorrect. The link function does not transform the response; it makes it so that you're modeling a transformed version of the expected value. e.g. the log link means you're modeling $\log( E(Y) )$... This is totally different from log-transforming the response---when you log-transform the response in an otherwise unlinked GLM, you are modeling $E(\log(Y))$.

Comment: If I were to elect the most useful comment in the whole CV, @gammer 's here would probably win by a fair margin.