# Nested mixed effects anova with lmer

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

[image]

I want to analyze some data from an experimental study with 3 factors:
treatN= nutrient manipulation 2levels N=nutrients added, A=ambient (fixed effect)

treatH= herbivory manipulation 3 levels C=ambient, H=moderate herbivory, HH=high herbivory (fixed effect)

Factor S= performed in 2 sites A and B(random effect)

I measured some response variables at the end of the experiment (area, necro...)
I want to perform a three way anova or any glm with mixed effects and with treat N and treatH nested in Factor S.

Q1:I used the package lmerTest, is this the right code?

```
   m2 = lmer(area~ treatN*treatH + (1|FactorS) , data=data)
```

Q2:I assume that lmer is a glm and thus the errors don´t need to be normal? If not how can I test this?

Q3: I tried glm models

```
    m4=glm(area ~ treatN*treatH + (1|FactorS), data=data, family=Gamma (link=identity))
```

but I get an error

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(1, FactorS) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors

how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Q1:** To know if the model is correct we need more information. It depends on how you randomized the `TreatN` and `TreatH` combinations in each site (i.e. `FactorS`). If you assigned the `TreatN` and `TreatH` combinations as a completely randomized design then I would say that yes your model is correct. If you randomized the the treatment combinations as a randomized complete block design I think the model should be:

```
m2 = lmer(area ~ treatN*treatH + (1|FactorS/replicate), 
          data = data)
```

because your replicate/block is nested within location.

**Answer Q2:** `lmer` fits mixed-effect models and is a type of generalized linear mixed model with a Gaussian distribution. The function `glm()` can't fit random effects.

**Answer Q3:** You can't fit the model you specified using the `glm()` function unless you treat `FactorS` as a fixed-effect; you could use `glmer()` function doing the following:

```
m4 = glmer(area ~ treatN*treatH + (1|FactorS), 
           data = data, family = Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

If your data follows a normal distribution you can also use the Gaussian distribtion in `glmer`, which is the same as doing the analysis in `lmer`.

```
m4 = glmer(area ~ treatN*treatH + (1|FactorS), 
           data = data, family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

(this will give you a warning saying you should just use `lmer` instead).

Here are a few links that can help you decide what distribution to use in your analysis:
[When to use gamma GLMs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67547/when-to-use-gamma-glms)