# What are the assumptions of a Gamma GLM or GLMM for hypothesis testing?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, glmm, gamma-distribution

What are the assumptions when doing hypothesis testing using a Gamma GLM or GLMM? Are the residuals suppose to be normally distributed and is heteroscedasticity a concern like the Gaussian (normal) distribution? Do you test the assumptions in the same fashion Levene Tests of individual fixed effects, residual and qqplots, and Shapiro-Wilks test?

Discussion of when to use Gamma Glm and Glmm is found here:

[When to use gamma GLMs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67547/when-to-use-gamma-glms/67548)

However, I found little to no discussion of the assumptions and how to test them?

**Edit 1:** Requested Example residual plots- are any of these a concern. Levene's test, comes back significant.

Residuals are plotted using this code. Time (Obs) is the ordinal factor levels from the data

```
modelresiduals = residuals(Gama_model)
plot(modelresiduals)
plot(y = modelresiduals, x = Model_data2$Obs)
```

**1. All resids-**

[image]

**2. By time**

[image]

**Edit 2** Based on comment suggestions- Patterns look good

```
ypred = predict(gama_model)
res = residuals(gama_model, type = 'pearson')
plot(ypred,res)
hist(res)
plot(res)
plot(y = res, x = Model_data$Obs)
```

**3. Pearson histograms- based on answer code**
[image]

**4. Pearson vs pred (link scale)- based on answer code**
[image]

**5. All Pearson residual- based on answer code**
[image]

**6. Pearson residual by Time- based on answer code**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the residuals suppose to be normally distributed...

No.  The distribution of $y\vert x$ is assumed to be gamma, and I don't think that $X - \mathbb{E}(X)$ is gamma for $X\sim \text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$.  The deviance residuals, on the other hand, should be normal.

> is heteroscedasticity a concern like the Gaussian (normal) distribution?

Heteroscedasticity should be observed since the variance changes with the mean.

Here is an example of Gamma regression in R.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Simulate
set.seed(0)
N <- 250
x <- runif(N, -1, 1)
a <- 0.5
b <- 1.2
y_true <- exp(a + b * x)
shape <- 2
y <- rgamma(N, scale = y_true/shape, shape = shape)

#Model
plot(x,y)
model <- glm(y ~ x, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
summary(model)

#Deviance residuals
ypred = predict(model)
res = residuals(model, type = 'deviance')
plot(ypred,res)
hist(res)

#Deviance GOF

deviance = model$deviance
p.value = pchisq(deviance, df = model$df.residual, lower.tail = F)
# Fail to reject; looks like a good fit.
```

For more on GLMs, I would recommend *Extending the Linear Model* by Faraway.

Comment: so am I correct in saying that if my data is hetersocedastic in time (ie. Cone shaped), if I want to do hypothesis tests with pairwise comparisons and I'm doing a gamma glmm, it's not a concern like it would be in a linear mixed model(Gaussian)?

Comment: That should be correct. The variance should change with the mean for a Gamma Glm

Comment: "Heteroscedasticity should be observed since the variance changes with the mean." This is true for the modeled **response** variable but not for the residuals vs. the predicted values as part of the model validation process? Your `plot(ypred,res)` looks good and there is no residual pattern present.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, thank you for clarifying.  The response should be heteroskedastic, but the deviance residuals should not.

Comment: OK! I wasn't exactly sure what @DevonOliver meant (modeled response or residual) when he said "so am I correct in saying that if my data is hetersocedastic in time...it's not a concern..."

Comment: @DemetriPananos  if a levennes test of the residuals(without specifying deviance) for one of thefixed effects (time; since thats the example ive been using)came back significant, is that a concern .

Comment: It isn't normally recommended to use those sorts of tests for model diagnostics.  Can you plot and post your residuals?

Comment: I agree with Demetri. You shouldn't use those tests to assess whether assumptions are met. I mostly use Pearson residuals and not Deviance residuals for model validation  - although both (Pearson and Deviance residuals) are defined in Faraway's book to do diagnostic plots. This paper might be helpful too (see Step 7): https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12577

Comment: @DemetriPananos added requested plots

Comment: @DevonOliver Tough for me to say without any context for the problem

Comment: @DemetriPanano In general, I should plot deviance residuals against preds and if there is no pattern, I should consider it good to go? Other than the Chi-sq test you listed is there any formal test?

Comment: @DevonOliver Doesn't seem to be a pattern, but there is something up with the residuals.  That test is called a "Deviance goodness of fit test"

Comment: @DevonOliver I used a regular GLM.  If you are using a mixed model, they are likely evaluated differently.  I would suggest you talk to a statistician at your institution about this.  I cant help without understanding what we are modelling

Comment: This really helped my understanding; I think I got in my own head and went down a wormhole. I generally live in the Poisson (Neg. Bin) and Binomial world or have much cleaner data. I will be sticking to Pearson and deviance resid plots going forward. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 4):

A nice approach for checking the fit of your assumed model to the data, accounting for features, such as, over-dispersion, non-normality, zero-inflation is the simulated scaled residuals provided by the [**DHARMa**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DHARMa) package. If your assumed model is correct, these residuals should have a uniform distribution. You can find more details on the procedure they are defined and used in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) of the package.

As an example, using the simulated example above, I compare below the fit of the Gamma model to the fit of the wrong normal model:

```r
set.seed(0)
N <- 250
x <- runif(N, -1, 1)
a <- 0.5
b <- 1.2
y_true <- exp(a + b * x)
shape <- 2
y <- rgamma(N, scale = y_true / shape, shape = shape)

gamma_model <- glm(y ~ x, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
normal_model <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian())

library("DHARMa")
check_gamma_model <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = gamma_model, n = 500)
plot(check_gamma_model)
```

[image]

```r
check_normal_model <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = normal_model, n = 500)
plot(check_normal_model)
```

[image]

Comment: note if  using glmmtmb for mixed models...random effects can make residual vs predicted line plots go haywire....despite good fit and lack of overdispersion..thanks for addition

Comment: In my **GLMMadaptive** package (https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) that fits similar models as the **glmmTMB** but using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature instead of the Laplace approximation it works. For an example you may check: https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html

Answer (score 1):

For checking the deviance goodness-of-fit statistic for a Generalized Linear Model like a Gamma Regression Model I recommend to follow the instructions on slide 18/19 of [Technical University Munich](https://www.groups.ma.tum.de/fileadmin/w00ccg/statistics/czado/lec8.pdf) respectively on slide 104 of [Technical University Graz](http://www.stat.tugraz.at/courses/files/GLMSlidesHSE.pdf).

That is, if dispersion parameter `disp` can not be assumed to be '1', the residual deviance test, i.e. calculating the p-value, should be applied on the scaled deviance, since the scaled statistic follows the chi square distribution (as outlined in the cited slides), e.g.:

`p.value = pchisq(myModel$deviance/summary(myModel$disp), df = myModel$df.residual, lower.tail = F)`

Comment: Actually you should use `summary(myModel)$disp`