# Model Verification for Gamma GLMM, different between qqplot and DHARMA

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, gamma-distribution, diagnostic

I am working with a dataset where the response variable looks like an in-between of normal and gamma distribution

**Edit: Including model formula and output, as requested, below**

[image: histogram of response values]

￼

I’m using lme4 because I also have a random effect structure (treatment|farm_id)
In calculating AICc values of the null models for both distributions I got - gamma AICc (-158.3) and normal AICc (-61.5)

Implying the gamma is a better fit, correct?

During model verification I’ve run into some issues though. I’ve mainly been following the advice from this post:
[What are the assumptions of a Gamma GLM or GLMM for hypothesis testing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390063/what-are-the-assumptions-of-a-gamma-glm-or-glmm-for-hypothesis-testing)

GAMMA MODEL VERIFICATION

```
res.gammaModel <- resid(gammaModel)
qqnorm(res.gammaModel)
qqline(res.gammaModel)›
```

￼[image: QQ Plot of Gamma]

```
ypred = predict(gammaModel)
res = residuals(gammaModel, type = 'pearson')
plot(ypred,res)
```

￼[image: Pearson Residuals vs Predicted]

I feel like the QQplot isn’t great but isn’t bad and the residuals versus predicted aren’t showing patterns

```
plot(y = res, x = scaled.originalData$treatment)
```

￼
[image: Treatment vs Residuals]

```
plot(y = res, x = scaled.originalData$explanatoryVariable)
```

￼
[image: Explanatory Variables vs Residuals]

But then…

```
plot(y = res.gammaModel, x = originalData$responseVariable)
```

￼[image: Response Variable Observed/Original vs Residuals]

Here I can’t use x = gammaModel$Obs because its a glmm I guess? And I have some NA values in my data that I needed to get rid of so maybe thats where I went wrong?

Furthermore using DHARMA for **the gamma distribution**

￼
[image: DHARMA Diagnostics Gamma Distribution]

I’m not really sure where I’m going wrong?
I’m using model.sel() and these plots are from the top model (delta AICc only 1 better than the null model).

On the otherhand, the top model of the model.sel() for **the normal distribution** set of models was the null model (by delta AICc 4) and the DHARMA QQ plot looked better

[image: DHARMA Diagnostics Gaussian Distribution]
￼
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit- Formulas and output** - on another note, I realized I am using REML for lmer and ML for glmer - I include the output for an lmer run on ML at the end...

```
gammalmm <- glmer(response  ~ exVar + (treatment|farm_id), data=scaled.originalData, family = Gamma, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)))

    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: Gamma  ( inverse )
Formula: response ~ exVar + (treatment | farm_id)
   Data: scaled.originalData
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
-160.2394 -120.6222   89.1197 -178.2394       594 
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Std.Dev. Corr       
 farm_id     (Intercept) 0.3859              
             treatmentBG 0.2714   -0.91      
             treatmentCC 0.3824    0.12 -0.17
 Residual                0.3192              
Number of obs: 603, groups:  farm_id, 9
Fixed Effects:
 (Intercept)         exVar  
     1.20526       0.01206 


lmm <- lmer(response  ~ 1 + (treatment|farm_id), data=scaled.originalData)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: response ~ 1 + (treatment | farm_id)
   Data: scaled.originalData
REML criterion at convergence: -77.7584
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Std.Dev. Corr       
 farm_id     (Intercept) 0.25875             
             treatmentBG 0.09519  -0.47      
             treatmentCC 0.18723   0.00 -0.31
 Residual                0.21336             
Number of obs: 603, groups:  farm_id, 9
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
     0.7496 


Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: response ~ 1 + (treatment | farm_id)
   Data: scaled.originalData
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
-65.0964 -29.8811  40.5482 -81.0964      595 
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Std.Dev. Corr       
 vfarm_id    (Intercept) 0.24687             
             treatmentBG 0.09501  -0.49      
             treatmentCC 0.18716   0.00 -0.31
 Residual                0.21337             
Number of obs: 603, groups:  farm_id, 9
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
     0.7495
```

And the DHARMA for the lmm fit with Maximum likelihood

[image: DHARMA lmm ML]

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is the difference between the the two models behind the two DHARMa plots ? Please include the model formulae and output for both models.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I really appreciate it. I bolded what each of the DHARMa plots is for and added the formulas and outputs.