# Distribution of an odds ratio under beta prior

Tags: distributions, bayesian

I would like to derive the distribution of the odds ratio $r := \frac{p_1/(1-p_1)}{p_0/(1-p_0)}$ with beta prior, specifically, $p_0, p_1 \in [0,1]$, $p_0 \sim beta(39.5,  635.5), p_1 \sim beta(22.5,  658.5)$. I don't know how to derive its analytical density form other than change of random variable, but a change of random variable from $(p_0, p_1)$ to $(r, p_1)$ doesn't lead me to a solution because of the complication of integrating the joint distribution of $(r, p_1)$ to get the marginal distribution of $r$. So I simulate it by R:

```
n=1000
r <- rep(0, n)
p0 <- rbeta(n, 39.5,  635.5) 
p1 <- rbeta(n, 22.5,  658.5)
r = (p1/(1-p1)) / (p0/(1-p0))
hist(r, plot=TRUE)
```

Is it possible to derive the analytical form of $r$ density?

What kind of distribution is it? Thanks!

Comment: With parameters this large, for many purposes you can closely approximate the distributions of the $\sqrt{p_i}$ with Normal distributions. For instance, $\sqrt{p_0} \sim$ Normal$(0.241186, 0.0186454)$ approximately. The CDFs differ by at most $0.004$. This enables you to capitalize on the extensive knowledge of ratios of normal variates. You can go further and approximate the root odds $\sqrt{p_i/(1-p_i)}$ with normal distributions, too (although the approximations are not quite as good).

Comment: Do you also think that the distribution of the odd ratio does not have an anlytical form, regardless how big the parameters of the beta priors are?

Comment: That's right.  The odds *do* have an analytical form, but their ratio appears intractable.

Comment: What approximation of do you think of for the distribution of the odd ratios

Comment: [Search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+ratio). You will have to be selective, but there's good stuff there.  One of the hits is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3640 with some good references in the answer by @ars.

Comment: Memory finally kicked in. Note that if $X\sim Beta$, $X/(1-X)$ is [beta prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution), so you're talking about a ratio of independent beta primes. Beta primes are connected to F distributions, so you may want to think about convolutions of logs of F random variables.

Comment: @Glen_b: could you explain why and how "Beta primes are connected to F distributions, so you may want to think about convolutions of logs of F random variables"? What is the distribution for the ratio of two independent beta primes?

Comment: And for logs of F, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_z-distribution). Since beta primes are scaled F, a convolution of a pair of shifted logFs should have the distribution of the log of the required quantity. If it's not algebraically nice (and it probably won't be), you might do that numerically.

Comment: The connection between F and Beta prime is explicit at the link I gave on beta primes, all you have to do is look. I don't know what the distribution of the ratio of independent beta primes is, *which is why I was talking about working with the logs*, since the problem reduces to simple convolution on the log-scale.