# Convergence of kernel density estimate as the sample size grows

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, large-data, density-estimation

Let $X\sim\text{Normal}(0,1)$ and let $f_X$ be its probability density function. I conducted some numerical experiments in the software Mathematica to estimate $f_X$ via a kernel method. Let $\hat{f}_X^M$ be the kernel density estimate using a sample of length $M$. Let 
$$\epsilon=E\left[\|f_X-\hat{f}_X^M\|_\infty\right]$$ 
be the error ($E$ is the expectation). I noticed that the error decreases with $M$ until a certain length $M_0$ from which the error stabilizes. For example, in Mathematica, the built-in function `SmoothKernelDistribution` employs the Gaussian kernel with Silverman's rule to determine the bandwidth by default. In the following figure in log-log scale, I show the error $\epsilon$ for different values of $M$ growing geometrically, where the expectation that defines $\epsilon$ is estimated using 20 realizations of $\|f_X-\hat{f}_X^M\|_\infty$. I also plot the estimated $90\%$ confidence interval for $\|f_X-\hat{f}_X^M\|_\infty$ (dashed lines).

[image]

Observe that the error decreases linearly in log-log scale (that is, at rate $O(M^{-r})$), up to a certain length $M$ where it starts to stabilize. Also, the confidence intervals become more narrow in the end. Is this issue due to accumulated numerical errors? Is it due to Silverman's rule?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the built-in function of Mathematica, `SmoothKernelDistribution` (its interpretation of Silverman's selection). If you implement the estimator
$$ \hat{f}_X^M(x)=\frac{1}{Mh}\sum_{i=1}^M K\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right) $$
yourself, where $x_1,\ldots,x_M$ is the data, the kernel $K$ is the density function of a $\text{Normal}(0,1)$ distribution, and the bandwidth $h$ is $1.06\,\hat{\sigma}_X\,M^{-1/5}$, then the error tends to zero as $M$ grows with no problem:

[image]

The bandwidth selected by `SmoothKernelDistribution` seems to be too large when $M$ gets bigger, which implies a biased estimate (error stabilization) with small variance (more narrow confidence interval).

Any other response will be welcomed.

Comment: This answer is plausible, +1.  Consider asking the good people at the SE  [Mathematica.se] site about this, too, to identify the bug more precisely.

Comment: It would be helpful to show your *Mathematica* code as you seem to be saying *Mathematica* does it wrong.  Also, a response is given at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212764/about-silvermans-bandwidth-selection-in-smoothkerneldistribution/212773#212773.

Comment: Well, *Mathematica* does seem to do it wrong for sample sizes greater than 100,000.  See answer at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212764/about-silvermans-bandwidth-selection-in-smoothkerneldistribution.