# Free very basic downloadable printable stats textbook

Tags: statistical-significance, references, descriptive-statistics

I volunteer teach a (very) basic stats course at a local medium/high security prison. My intent is just to get across basic ideas so that the inmates can make some contact with that branch of thinking.
I have to purchase my own supplies (and books) and I have a difficult time finding enough of the same kind of book, at a level I like and in sufficient quantities and at a doable price.

This is a very tough prison system and there is essentially nothing but a white board and an eraser. 
I've constructed a basic set of ten lessons that covers early concepts up to and including hypothesis testing, correlations, regressions.

I would like to find a book to reporduce that is simple yet will provide more background that I can provide to distribute to each class.

These guys generally have weak math backgrounds and no interest beyond 'knowing' something.
I have looked at all the links at [Free statistical textbooks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks) and they miss the target - either too abbreviated or too complex.

Any help, ideas would be well appraciated.

Comment: Similar [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/176671/84191)

Comment: Can you say whether the Openintro [book](http://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php) at the other link was too high a level or too low? Openintro have [a couple of other books](https://www.openintro.org/stat/)