# A good alternative to data binning?

Tags: dataset, discrete-data, continuous-data, binning

I read many times that data binning of continuous variables is a very bad idea.

For instance, let's take something like heart rate and let's define the following 2 bins:

(125 - 135), (136 - 145)

Let's say that (136 - 145) corresponds to a hard effort.

If your exercise session causes your heart rate to stay at 135 consistently, data binning will reveal that you spent no time exercising hard, while you were 1 beat per minute away from that bin during the whole time.

Obviously, this is an exaggerated example to illustrate the point.

I was thinking to weigh each second spent at a given heart rate based on its distance from the centers of the bins it falls between.

For instance, in the example above, 140.5 would be 100% in the second bin, 135.5 would be 50% in the first bin and 50% in the second bin, 130 would be 100% in the first bin.

Does that sound like nonsense or a reasonable solution?

What would be a better way?

Comment: Why not just leave it as continuous?

Comment: Classification or regression? What is your response and do you have any other covariates?

Comment: @PeterFlom It is assumed that exercise in specific bins produces specific physiological adaptations. In order to be able to quantify how an exercise session contributed to the various physiological adaptations, binning seems attractive, but...

Comment: Yes, OK, but the assumptions about the bins are designed to allow a person who is exercising to make a decision about how hard to exercise; they are coarser then the raw data. It seems unlikely that the physiology of a heart rate of 135 is the same as 125 but different from 136.  So, you should account for the binning at a later stage in the analysis - when you are making recommendations.

Comment: @Laurent, you get quantification with regression also. Think of the simplest case: a line: you get both a $y$-intercept *quantity*, but also the quantity of how much $y$ changes by given a 1-unit increase in $x$. Of course the exciting and fun stuff comes with multiple regression and interactions, and nonlinear regression with possibly complex relationships between $y$ and a given $x$. But these are all *quantified*.

Comment: Your proposal is not nonsense. Mathematically, it is a linear spline. Splines are well-studied in regression and often are a good choice to handle non-linear relationships among dependent and independent variables, as discussed (in detail) in [Frank Harrell's book](http://www.amazon.com/Regression-Modeling-Strategies-Applications-Statistics/dp/0387952322) *inter alia.* Splines are more flexible tools than your approach, though, indicating that a studied application of them cannot be any worse and could be somewhat (or perhaps a lot) better.

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes, I agree that any bin boundary will be arbitrary and hard to justify, but there is an expectation that certain zones have certain meaning. I must respect that convention.

Comment: @Alexis What would be x, what would be y? How would I glance at a regression line/curve and figure out how much time I spent in any give bin/zone?

Comment: If the data are continuous, what happens to someone whose heart rate is 135.6?

Comment: My point was **not binning is quantitative**. Binning suffers from loss of power and the potential for quite serious aggregation bias, this is true both theoretically, and in my experience with actual data.

Comment: @Alexis I got you, but this is as much a data visualization problem as it is a data analysis problem.

Comment: Therefore why not use the most assumption-free data visualization techniques? I.e. nonparametric smoothing regression that lets the relationship between $y$ (outcome) and $x$ predictor speak for itself, without imposing arbitrary (and potentially quite biasing) aggregation structure onto it?

Comment: @Alexis Thank you for your help, I'll look into that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the justification for unsupervised discretization of continuous variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104402/what-is-the-justification-for-unsupervised-discretization-of-continuous-variable)

Comment: Other dup: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232088/99274 shows the effect of mean x-value bin assignments.