# For data reduction, what is this technique called?

Tags: data-preprocessing

I have observations X along with their labels Y. I then create a histogram of Y. I then remove observations such that the histogram still retains the same distinct shape.

Does anyone know what data reduction technique this is called?

Comment: If this is done purely visually, perhaps the nicest name for it would be "data fudging." If you are applying a definite algorithm, and are willing to disclose it in your post, then perhaps more could be said.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of this in my head, I thought that there would be something like this already out there. I was thinking of a way to reduce the amount of data that I had, but still retain the original distribution.

Comment: Such data reduction is usually obtained by simple random sampling of the data: "subsampling," but in some cases other forms of *controlled* sampling can be used: I would expect any answers to explain some of the possibilities.  For problems that might occur in using histograms for subsampling please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram.

Comment: It might be a uniform sub-sampling.  Might be class-weighted subsampling.  Might be related to an unscented transform (think unscented-Kalman Filter).  Without more clear details it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing would qualify as a form of **Stratified Random Sampling**. (Though typically you'd stratify according to things like "Sex" and "Nationality" and not according to the bins of a histogram...)

Comment: I've heard of Stratified Random sampling but, my output is a continuous value. I haven't seen Stratified Random sampling used with continuous outputs before, is it common?

Comment: Well, what the technique is and whether or not it's the best technique for the job are two different questions...

Comment: What you initially describe would qualify as stratified random sampling but you would probably want to do something more along the lines of bootstrapping/resampling. Thus, to deal with what is (presumably) a *huge* dataset you'd end up taking lots of manageably-sized samples from your dataset, etc., etc... Note: For more in-depth answers you'd probably need to be more specific w/r/t what it is you're trying to do and what you have, etc]