# Modeling Smooth Decay on Logarithmic Y

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

I have an empirical distribution that looks like the the image below and I hoping to model it with some parametric distribution.  The `X` axis measures **"number of buckets"**, while the `Y` axis measures **number of unique users in a given number of buckets*.

I am starting to explore the problem, but our prior knowledge about the problem would suggest that users choose to be in a bucket independently of each other and independently of other buckets they belong to.

For example the left-most bar in blue effectively shows that buckets of sizes between `0-1000` are the most common ones in the data.

From the list of "known" **parametric distributions**, what **type of distribution** could capture this problem or exhibit the pattern shown below?

[image: distribution]

Comment: Looks exponential to me.

Comment: Beware trying to [judge distributional shape from a histogram with very few bins](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram/51753#51753). Can you do one with about 4-10 times as many bins, and maybe an exponential QQ-plot? What does a histogram or KDE of the logs look like?

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Looks exponential to me. – Sycorax

Beware [trying to judge distributional shape from a histogram with very few bins](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram/51753#51753). Can you do one with about 4-10 times as many bins, and maybe an exponential QQ-plot? What does a histogram or KDE of the logs look like? – Glen_b

Another illustration is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375647/how-long-is-a-distribution-considered-normal/375762#375762).