# How to characterize opposite of heavy tailed distribution?

Tags: histogram, heavy-tailed

I have a bunch of histogram distributions. In some of the histograms (let's call these Type-A), the initial 2-3 bins are extremely tall compared to the remaining bins. In others, there is no discernible pattern (let's call these Type-B). I would like to differentiate between Type-A and Type-B distributions. Now, Type-A seems like the opposite of heavy-tailed distribution (heavy-headed ?). Is there a way to characterize such distributions ?

Ideally, I would like to accomplish this in such a way that the differentiating measure (between Type-A and Type-B) holds for a reasonable range of histogram bin sizes.

Examples:

Type-A:

[image: Type-A]

Type-B:

[image: Type-B]

Comment: It sounds more like "heavily right skewed" vs I-can't-guess-what ... can you show examples?

Comment: On the "range of histogram bin-sizes" thing -- you can't always get consistence from histograms. Even changing bin-origin can lead to [dramatic changes](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram/51753#51753) in some cases

Comment: @Glen_b Added examples ...

Comment: What you have drawn there is a bar chart, not a histogram. Are these Likert-scale items?

Comment: @Glen_b The x-axis corresponds to item categories and the histogram measures their frequency. These are not Likert-scale items.

Comment: Do these item categories have some kind of order with an inherent meaning, or are the numbers "1" through "8" merely convenient labels for them?

Comment: @whuber They do have an order.