# Approximate 2d histogram to Gaussian distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, histogram

I have a source of data that follows this bivariant Gaussian distribution:

[image]

The same source of data produces this 2-dimensional histogram:

[image]

Computing the 2d histogram is much less expensive however the source is better described using a Gaussian. My question is: is there a way of approximating the 2d histogram to the bivariate Gaussian shown above? Maybe some sort of filtering using the mean and covariance from the source?

---

Both distribution maps (i.e. the images from above) are generated from values ranging [0,255]. In other words, my source outputs integer values between 0 and 255.

Comment: Do note that bin choice greatly affects the "shape" of the histogram and thus it can fit to different distributions.

Comment: @gunbl4d3, reducing the number of bins results in a lower resolution representation of the data. Not sure about the "greatly affects"...

Comment: What do you mean by "approximating the 2d histogram to the Gaussian"?

Comment: @gunbl4d3 is not necessarily talking about resolution, but also things like [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51753/127790) (which I would call [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)).

Comment: @Tim, I'd like to find a way of making the 2d histogram look like the 2d Gaussian. (see the images in the question body).