# What is the sample size required to estimate a multivariate joint histogram?

Tags: estimation, histogram, multivariate-distribution

The required sample size for estimating a multivariate joint histogram is something that I expect to depend on multiple factors such as the distributional properties of the data-generating process (e.g. multivariate Gaussian vs Pareto), [choice of bin endpoints](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram/51753#51753), number of bins, and the number of variables. Therefore I don't expect a single number for the appropriate sample size, but perhaps a collection of functions or other relations.

Are there relations/bounds/functions for working out (possibly conservative) sample size requirements for estimating multivariate histograms?

Comment: The answer must depend on which property or properties of the joint distribution you wish to estimate and how accurately you need to estimate them.  Could you describe the actual problem you face?

Comment: I have a few use cases. Let's take estimating mutual information from multimodal thin-tailed distributions as an example.

Comment: What are the possibilities for these distributions?  Is your problem fully nonparametric or not?

Comment: It is fully non-parametric. There's no supposition of location and shape properties around modes, nor is the number of modes known.

Comment: Then there's no general answer.