# Visually inspecting normality of variables

Tags: data-visualization, normality-assumption, diagnostic

I'm using R to plot some graphs for visually inspecting the normality of variables that will go into a linear regression model. Except for a histogram and a QQ plot, what other graphics could I use?

Comment: PP plot. The classic paper Wilk, M.B., & Gnanadesikan, R. 1968. Probability plotting methods for the analysis of data. _Biometrika_ 55: 1-17 which introduced the terminology of QQ and PP plots is very much worth reading. The QQ plot remains the best in my opinion.

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64026/benefits-of-using-qq-plots-over-histograms

Comment: Also density plots and box plots can be useful to highlight different aspects of violations of normality. As an aside, variables that go into a regression do not have to be normally distributed; the residuals from the model do.

Comment: Histograms are okay, [with appropriate levels of caution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram/51753#51753). I'd second the recommendation of the QQ plot as probably the best choice. =

Comment: And please do not forget that most regression models do not assume normality of *any* of their variables, so why are you doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Peter Flom a third option could be the boxplot.

The picture below shows two distributions (with n=1000):

1. On the left column a Normal distribution with $\mu = 4$ and $\sigma = 1$ and,
2. On the right a two parameter Weibull distribution, with shape = 1.5 and scale = 2.

The first line shows the histograms and the second line illustrates a quantile-quantile plot (with the normal distribution as the baseline for comparison). The third line contains the boxplot plots). Note how the Weibull presents non symmetric whiskers in the boxplot.

[image]

Here is the `R` code to reproduce the picture

```
set.seed(77)  
x=rnorm(1000,4,1)
y=rweibull(1000,shape=1.5,scale=2)

par(mfrow=c(3,2),mar=c(5,4,1.5,2))

hist   (x,prob=T, main="Normal ~ (4,1)  "                  , ylab="Density"          , xlab="Quantile"          , ylim=c(0,0.6), xlim=c(0,8))
hist   (y,prob=T, main="Weibull ~ (1.5,2)"                 , ylab="Density"          , xlab="Quantile"          , ylim=c(0,0.6), xlim=c(0,8))
qqplot (x,x     , main="Normal ~ (4,1) x Normal ~ (4,1)"   , ylab="Normal quantiles" , xlab="Normal quantiles"                              )
qqplot (x,y     , main="Normal ~ (4,1) x Weibull ~ (1.5,2)", ylab="Weibull quantiles", xlab="Normal ~ quantiles"                            )
boxplot(x       , main="Normal ~ (4,1)  "                  , ylab="Quantile"         , xlab=""                  , ylim=c(0,8               ))
boxplot(y       , main="Weibull ~ (1.5,2)"                 , ylab="Quantile"         , xlab=""                  , ylim=c(0,8               ))
```

Lastly, just to emphasize the hint provided by Peter, regression assumption of normality is observed over the residuals' distribution and not the predictors'.